# How to convert open-ssl created private key to openssh private key?

Tags: ssh, openssl, openssh, conversion, key-authentication

I have created an open-ssl private key which I would like to use to connect to my server through ssh. The openssl key was generated during certificate creation and I have to use this key on putty. The problem is that puttygen only allows openssh type keys to be converted to putty keys. How do I convert my open-ssl private key to openssh private key so I can convert it to putty key? The length of the private key is 2048 bits.

Comment: Why not just create a new OpenSSH key private key?

Comment: Because I had to use openssl to create a self signed certificate which the server requires. In this process was the private key also generated.

Comment: But what does the self-signed certificate and its key have to do with SSH?

Comment: Are you using certificate-based SSH authentication? (As described in the `CERTIFICATES` section of the `ssh-keygen(1)` manpage.)

Comment: Have a look at `ssh-keygen`'s `-i` and `-m` options, anyway.

Comment: @muru Tried to use the -i flag and it says `buffer_get_string_ret: bad string length`. So I cannot use the `i` flag to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The RSA key formats look mighty similar to me.

```
bash-4.1$ openssl genrsa 4096 > whoble
...
bash-4.1$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f bobble
...
bash-4.1$ head -c 123 whoble ; echo
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJJwIBAAKCAgEAw22KzezlaVt6/lAkuTeLNVyrPIK8rjMchGPmUBp6Gx1Bkcjk
zjoWNNH1d0gxVd0Yw2RmpJVVnH
bash-4.1$ head -c 123 bobble ; echo
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEoQIBAAKCAQEA1tUSesz83DwMiQj6aWDMRd/5DISMBnp9jXZVzWwmD61FqlO/
ZhbmdBFMvNUIZNcHVQjqL/Gso0
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: They are not similar enought for puttygen to convert a key for use with putty. I have tried, but it tells me it doesn't recognize the format. Keys generated with `ssh-keygen` convert fine with puttygen.